# Cluster Analysis on a 20,000+ row data set using K-Means 'tot.withinss' not working in R

Tags: r, clustering, k-means

I have 20,000+ rows of data around 7 columns. I tried to do cluster analysis on it using K-Means where k= 5. When I attempted to plot the clusters, it was not helpful at all, too much data so it all overlapped. So I wanted to use other ways of analysing the clusters using 'tot.withinss'. For some reason however, despite indicating I want 5 clusters, when I run the 'tot.withinss' I only get one number. What am I missing? Code below:

```
> divy.k5 <- kmeans(divy.std, centers=4, iter.max=500, nstart=1000,algorithm = "MacQueen")
> divy.k5$tot.withinss
[1] 691262.4
```

Comment: tot.withinss should be a single number, namely the total within-cluster sum of squares.  And don't you want centers=5?

Answer (score 3):

`tot.withinss` is a *total*.

Yes, that is supposed to be a single number. If you do 1000 runs on the same data with the same k, then you can use this number to select the best run (by the kmeans objective of least ss). The value cannot be compared across different k or data.

Answer (score 1):

Others have pointed out that `tot.withinss` is supposed to be a single number.

But your problem seems to be about plotting the results of a cluster analysis with 20,000 points and 7 variables.  One solution is to make the points very small. Another is to make the points nearly translucent. Yet another is to plot each cluster separately. Some combination of these should give you a graph that is readable, but, if not, you can simply take a random sample of each cluster and plot that.